# Curly braces with ` on React

Tags: javascript

I've a small problem with rendering.

```
const Image = React.createClass({
getInitialState(){
    return{
        imgUrl: 'cat.jpg'
    }
},

handleChange(e){
        e.target.classList.toggle('active')
},

render(){
    return (

        <div className="handler"

           style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.state.imgUrl + ')'}}
           onClick={this.handleChange}>

        </div>
    )
}
})

ReactDOM.render(
    <Image />,
    document.getElementById('home')
)
```

Right now I'm adding style for my div this way:

```
style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.state.imgUrl + ')'}}
```

When I'm trying to write this way:

```
`url({this.state.imgUrl})`
```

it just adds %7D and %7B symbols of { }

What's the correct way to write it and how I can to avoid " + "

Hope someone will help with this easy question :)

Comment: Don't you need a `$` in front of curly brace expressions?

Comment: yes, that's right, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `` `url(${this.state.imgUrl})` ``.

For your information, It is called **Template literals**.
See [this MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to get more information.

Comment: wow, yes, thank you. 

Forget about it. 

And about "Template literals" - forget the name on English :)